# Does Infectious Spell affect spells that have a target of "one creature"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, mythic-adventures

The mythic power Infectious Spell has this qualification

> Whenever you cast a spell that specifically targets a limited number of targets (such as “one creature/level” or “one or more creatures”) and has a duration longer than 1 round, you can expend one use of mythic power to make the spell infectious.

Do spells that specifically target only "one creature" count as a "limited number of targets"?

For examples, consider Hold Person ("One humanoid creature") — would it be a valid spell for Infectious Spell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

While the [archmage 3rd tier mythic path ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/archmage) infectious spell does, in fact, list only as examples of spells having a limited number of targets those spells targeting *one creature/level* and those spells targeting *one or more creatures*, because *one or more creatures* includes targeting only *one* creature, a spell that *only* targets one creature should also be a limited number of targets for the purposes of the special ability. (And this abrupt [2015 thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sq7g?How-many-targets-must-a-spell-have-to-work)—the only one I could find on the subject—agrees.)

The effect seems to function as printed even if only a lone target is affected, making the spell [*hold person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person) a fine choice for an infectious spell.